# Is there any way to enable sonarQube to use Dev branch instead of main in community edition?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube community edition support scanning the code present in the main branch. But I want to use sonarqube to scan my Dev branch. Since I want to use Dev branch for my active development and main branch for my releases.

I red some where we have this option in the community edition.
Please help me with your valuable answers.

Answer (score 0):

[On the following link](https://medium.com/cloudnesil/making-sonarqube-analysis-of-multiple-git-branches-with-docker-in-community-edition-48aaa768851) you can find:

> In the previous versions(before 7.7) of SonarQube we could analyze
> multiple branches of our project. But after that version we can
> analyze only master branch with SonarQube in Community edition.
>
> I suggest to use Developer Edition if you have enough budget. If you
> do not have enough budget there is a SonarQube plugin that you can
> make branch analysis with any branch.

[Link to plugin](https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin).